# Add an blank line at the end of the output

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and understand *`n* and "" can add blank line in the right place. I just cant seem to get it to properly put a blank line before or after the output

This is just a basic code that i created to get a better understanding of powershell, while the code does what i want it to do. now i sadly seem to struggle with the simple things of where to put *`n*

```
 Get-ADComputer -filter * | Where-Object {$_.name -like "test-*"} | ForEach-Object { systeminfo /s $_.name } | Select-String 'Host Name', 'Total Physical memory', 'Available Physical Memory' | Add-Content C:\scripts\RamConfig.txt
```

the output is correct it other than after like 30 computers it just stops. just looks sloppy because there is no blank line in between each AD computer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest *not* using a wildcard filter **ever** when working with the AD cmdlets.  Additionally, use `wmi` instead of `systeminfo.exe` since working with *objects* will always be easier than working with *strings*.

```
foreach ($computer in Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "test-*"') {
    $os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer.Name
    $mem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer.Name

    $hostname = $os.CSName
    $availMem = ($os.FreePhysicalMemory / 1GB).ToString('00.00')
    $totalMem = ($mem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB).ToString('00.00')

    @"
Host Name:                 $hostname
Total Physical Memory:     $totalMem GB
Available Physical Memory: $availMem GB

"@ | Add-Content -Path C:\scripts\RamConfig.txt
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add, using a CSV format for this task would make more sense.  You have a tabular output but you want it in a list for some reason.  It doesn't make logical sense to do that.

Comment: that only outputs the info for my current pc. it also does not fix my overall question. that being said i just added a like before "@

Comment: @chupathingy See my update.  I forgot to pass the `ComputerName` parameters.

Comment: now it goes through all the pcs in the AD but now it spits out a blank host name and the total memory is how much mem i have and then the available is 0/

Comment: @chupathingy Do you have *access* to those devices?  Take just one and try running those commands against it.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. i do have access to the computer and i ran it to check for only on PC that my original command worked for and i am still getting errors and its spitting out blank info for host and now all numbers i am asking for are 00.00. which i imagine has to do with the to string line

Comment: If you run `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $name | Format-List * -Force` against a computer, do you see the computername in the list of properties? @chupathingy

Comment: if i replace $name with a pc name yes but not with $name

Comment: @chupathingy I suspect it's an issue between RPC v. WINRM so I've reverted the answer to an older compatibility using `Get-WmiObject` instead.

Comment: well i got it to work but now i get 'The RPC server is unavailable for a large handful of pcs and get it for like 25 pcs.

Comment: @chupathingy that's an environment issue you'll see anywhere.  Test the connection before trying to grab info from them.

Comment: so as it turns out my head sysadmin never cleans up the ad so like half the computers are inactive.....wrote a script that cleans them up and now the script runs just fine.